# Is there a way to toggle walking mode with keyboard & mouse on the PC in Reckoning?

Tags: pc, kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

On the forums it seems like it is possible to walk with your character using a controller, but I can't find a keyboard shortcut that does the same thing.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest difference between a keyboard and a controller is that the directional input of a keyboard is digital (discrete set of values; in this case, binary -- pressed or not pressed), while the input from a controller's thumbstick is analog (continuous range of values)

The short of all this is that if you're using a keyboard, there's simply no way to move at *less* than full speed -- there's just no button implemented to move forward at half speed (or whatever).

The closest you'll get on a PC is entering stealth mode, which will slow you down and make you crouch, but this isn't actually a "walk" mode, it's just slower.

Comment: I'd still imagine that you should be able to implement a binary toggle for walk/run - maybe they'll do it in a patch :)

Comment: @Esti - They could, sure, they just haven't *yet*. ;)